# Delegate Access in Exchange 2010

Tags: windows, exchange, exchange-2010

How can I delegate access to a user/group so they can manage mobile phones within Exchange 2010?

I would like the user/group to be able to preform remote wipes on phones and provide a reset PIN.

[Manage Mobile Phones](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dy2P5.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Client Access Permissions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638131(v=exchg.141).aspx) article, we can know that if we want to manage Exchange activesync devices settings, it requires "Recipient Management" permission. So, the simplest way is to add the user/Group into this role group. Details see: [Add Members to a Role Group](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638143(v=exchg.141).aspx).

However, that role group permits them to do much more than just manage the Exchange activesync devices they are responsible for, so it doesn't align with the least privilege approach to security. The more sensible approach is to create a custom RBAC role and assign it to that user, or to a role group that the user can be made a member of. Details see: [Create a Custom Admin Role for Exchange using RBAC](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/nepapfe/2014/02/04/create-a-custom-admin-role-for-exchange-using-rbac/)